# Authenticating with Jetty through GWT button

Tags: gwt, forms-authentication, smartgwt, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to create a login page using SmartGWT and have been trying to get Form Authentication to work with the Jetty server embedded with the GWT plug-in for Eclipse. I have a page that takes a username and password using TextItems, then once the login button is pressed I need the authentication to take place.

I've set up my jetty-web.xml file to create a custom realm, which currently doesn't do anything but tell me it's methods are being called, just so I know it's working, as once I get in there, I pretty sure I can figure the rest out.

jetty-web.xml

```
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="SecurityHandler">
        <Call name="setUserRealm">
            <Arg>
                <New class="custom.realm.CustomRealm">
                    <Set name="name">CustomRealm</Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </Call>

        <Call name="setAuthenticator">
            <Arg>
                <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.security.FormAuthenticator">
                    <Set name="loginPage">/login.html</Set>
                    <Set name="errorPage">/login.html</Set>
                </New>
            </Arg>
        </Call>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

[edit 05/18 1:16pm]

My CustomRealm extends Jetty's HashUserRealm, dunno if that may cause issues, btu figured I'd mention it as well.

I've also set up a security constraint in my web.xml file

web.xml snippet

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>        
        <web-resource-name>Login</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint> -->

</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>CustomRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I'm fairly new to doing this type of stuff, tbh. I'm not sure I need the constraint. The  is commented out because when I had it uncommented the page wouldn't load, at all.

From what I've read, I gather that using the security constraint with Jetty should pop-up a browser login dialog. That's not what I want to have happen, and it actually doesn't anyways. So I'm unsure of what I'm doing wrong there.

I also found the RequestBuilder class in GWT, but that doesn't seem to be doing anything I want it to. I need the login button to somehow call the authenticate method in my custom realm. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this? Or at least be pointed in the right direction, cause I've been looking and haven't found anything.

thanks in advance.

[edit 05/18 8:56am] 
adding how my RequestBuilder is set up now after Peter's suggestion

```
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, "login.html");
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.append(URL.encode("j_username")).append("=").append(URL.encode(getUsername()));
postData.append("&");
postData.append(URL.encode("j_password")).append("=").append(URL.encode(getPassword()));
rb.setRequestData(postData.toString());
rb.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
    {
        if (response.getStatusCode() != Response.SC_OK)         
        {
            onError(request, new RequestException(response.getStatusText() + ":\n" + response.getText()));
            return;
        }

        if (response.getText().contains("Access Denied"))
        {
            Window.alert("Incorrect username or password entered. Please try again.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("IT WORKED!!!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception)
    {
        Window.alert(exception.getMessage());
    }
});

try
{
    rb.send();
}
catch (RequestException e)
{
    SC.say(e.getMessage());
}
```

[re-update]
If the auth-constraint is uncommented, the onModuleLoad method is never called. Anyone know of why it might be doing that?